# When should I stop playing endless mode in Plants vs Zombies?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I don't think there's already a clone question, if there is I apologize but I didn't find it.

It's **kinda of a spoiler** but not really a spoiler.

So I'm using this strategy and I have 142 flags:

[image]

The thing is since flag #50 I'm not noticing changes in the behaviour of the AI. Basically I'm winning easy, I have just to restore the *Pumpkin* shield on the plants.
I really don't care about doing 1000 flags so should I expect some increase in difficulty or is that it?

The version is **Game of the Year**.

Comment: I think your build can be improved by swapping the umbrella with the gloom to its left to kill imps more quickly, or leave out the umbrella altogether if you always bomb the catapults before they get a shot off. Also, bungee zombies never hit cob cannons, so if you move the rightmost two cob cannons in the pool one square further to the right, you don't need umbrellas. You can use the space either for two cattails to kill the balloons and help with the imps, or a winter pult and a twinflower to help protect the pumpkins in the pool and earn more money.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've searched fairly extensively and I can't find anything that suggests it gets harder.

Answer (score 7):

this guy hit 8000+ flags... so ...

endless is the best way to make money and farm plants/chocolate to you zen garden, you should stop when you get filled with all this stuff.